# Не загружается фото в ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Делаю приложение для фото. Сначала фотографирую, затем вывожу фотографию с карты памяти телефона на экран. На версии android 5.2 фото выводится как надо. На версии 7.1 фото не грузится совсем, при чем никакими способами.

Вот код:

```
File saveDir;
String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/123/TakenFromCamera.jpg";
File file = new File(_path);
Uri outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(_path));
        }
```

Comment: Возможно нужно запрашивать доступ , Runtime Permissions почитайте

Comment: Ошибки в логах есть? Какие именно?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том, что на андроид 6+ картинка в большом разрешении не выводится в ImageView. По этому приходится рескейлить её. Осталось решить, как правильно её уменьшить относительно разрешения экрана телефона.